# Symfony2: How to display/download a BLOB field

Tags: symfony, blob

For my client I have to use blob storage for some various files.

So I have created a independent bundle with a Blob class extends Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.
and with a boot function in the bundle class.

That works pretty fine I can write in the database Blob datas.

But I can't download any document after :/

I have got:

```
public function downloadAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    /* @var $entity Document */
    $entity = $em->getRepository('Lille3SapBundle:Document')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Document entity.');
    }

    $file = $entity->getFichier();

    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($file, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length' => sizeof($file),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$entity->getNomDocument().'"',
    ));

    return $response;
}
```

and I have got an Exception:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "resource" given.

in fact, the *$file* values is not the expected BLOB but something like *Resource id #123*

-> I have check blob data fields values, and they are ok in the database

So how can I force in the controller to have the blob row and not a *Resource id #111*

Comment: Can you show us the content of `getFichier` method? Is `resource` being generated in that call? If not it's a bit odd to store resource **handle** in you database...

Answer (score 28):

You can still use **BLOB** field for your field in DB as you initially planned.

In *createAction* store data as usual (with no base64_encode()):

```
$stream = fopen($entity->getFichier(),'rb');
$entity->setFichier(stream_get_contents($stream));
```

and in *downloadAction* just use:

```
$file = $entity->getFichier();
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(stream_get_contents($file), 
    200, 
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length' => sizeof($file),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$entity->getNomDocument().'"',
    ));

return $response;
```

**Explanation:**

**BLOB** fields are treated as *resource* variable which have no __toString() implementation.

```
gettype($file) -> "resource"
get_resource_type($file) -> "stream"
```

**stream_get_contents($file)** makes the magic here: gets **STRING** content from resource variable.

Comment: Don't forget to call `rewind($entity->getFichier());`, if you are getting stream straight from Doctrine entity's attribute.

Comment: @Rafal Gradziel It worked 90%. But I couldn't download the file. In the response I am getting the file contents as the output in the console. Any help ! !

Comment: I am trying to apply this but end up with PHP error: `Message:  fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given`

Comment: FYI I had issues with sizeof() always returning 1 and thus severely truncated files. I had to do `strlen($file)` instead of `sizeof($file)`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have got a (very uggly) solution:

Firstly: I changed the data type **blob** to **text** for the file attribute of Document entity.

Secondly: in createAction I've changed the setFichier call:

```
$stream = fopen($entity->getFichier(),'rb');
$entity->setFichier(base64_encode(stream_get_contents($stream)));
```

Thirdly: in downloadAction, I decode the text base64 text field:

```
$file = $entity->getFichier();              
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(base64_decode($file), 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length' => sizeof($file),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$entity->getNomDocument().'"',
));

return $response;
```

And now I can persist and download files as blob way...

Comment: I advise to delete the 'Content-Length' field which is problematic for some files