# symfony2 download file The Response content must be a string

Tags: php, symfony-2.5

i want download my pdf file where he's saved in my phpmyadmin 'blob'

i try this code:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $ma_base_de_donne = new myprojectdbEntity();

    $item = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('myprojectBundle:myprojectdbEntity')->find(5);
    if (!$item) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("File with ID 5 does not exist!");
    }
    $pdfFile = $item->getFichier(); //returns pdf file stored as mysql blob
    //$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=" . urlencode($pdfFile));
    $response = new Response($pdfFile, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
    //return $response;
    var_dump($response); die();
}
```

and i get this error :

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "resource" given.

help me please

thanks first

Comment: Try toString($pdfFile) as the first parameter of the response object?

Comment: looks like you are getting a resource. Try a `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($item);exit;` and see  what is in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: How to display/download a BLOB field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206963/symfony2-how-to-display-download-a-blob-field)

Answer (score 0):

Define a __toString() method in your entity object($pdfFile):

```
public function __toString() {
    return $name;
}
```

Or send directly the string in your response:

```
$response = new Response($pdfFile->getName(), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
```